# "~you start smelling the spice kicking in your kitchen."

Tags: word-meaning

This is from the [transcript of a podcast](https://www.npr.org/transcripts/1089175288).

> LEE: And keep in mind that gochugaru burns real quick. So if you're
> blooming it in oil or butter or following Eric's scrumptious gochugaru
> salmon recipe make sure to lower the heat when you start smelling the
> spice **kicking** in your kitchen.

I wonder what 'kick' means in the above context.

My sense is that it means 'give off a smell'.

Am I right?

Comment: I wonder whether it's an error (either in transcription, or a slip of the tongue) for **kicking in** _in your kitchen_. If something like a medication 'kicks in', it starts to take effect.

Comment: I listened to the audio from that portion. The host is reading from a script that has been probably been written from notes taken during an interview. It seems to me it should be just "kicking in", but whoever wrote the script wasn't familiar with the idiom and added "your kitchen" to force it to make sense. A person using that idiom as part of their own speech would gave said it with a slightly different emphasis. "kicking" is a slang term for good/awesome and maybe they thought the speaker was using it.